# Take data that is listed vertically and create multiple horizontal rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I take customer data adjust it and horizontally place it in Excel. I want to use VBA to do this.

I want this data placed on the next available row each time.

Also is there a way to automatically have a chunk of nine cells selected to be moved. I created a macro for one chunk of this data but cannot move further.

Current Code:

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-11, -4).Range("A1:A9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "US"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Company Order"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1 (407) 5556032"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " johndoe@aol.com"
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Starting Vertical List
[image]

Desired Result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following, just adjust your report workbook-worksheet variable (marked in the code).
Also I added a feature at the end to ask if want to delete vertical data, please test first replying "NO" with multiple report sets in order to test the sub without losing any data.

```
Option Explicit
Sub formatReport()
    
    'the grouping data size variable (in this case 9 rows per group)
    Dim groupSize As Integer: groupSize = 9
    
    'report data worksheet variable
    Dim wsh As Worksheet: Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) '--adjust to your report worksheet here
    
    'Insert a blank row in position 2 (new data will always be inserted in row2)
    wsh.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
    
    'variable to count group of data added
    Dim dataGroupAddedCount As Long: dataGroupAddedCount = 0
    
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wsh.Range("A" & wsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long: i = 3
    'Loop data
    Do While i <= lastRow
        If wsh.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo EvaluateNext
        Dim j As Long
        'first column were data will be inserted ("recipient" column)
        Dim firstColumn As Integer: firstColumn = 2
        For j = 0 To groupSize - 1
            wsh.Cells(2, firstColumn).Value = wsh.Cells(j + i, 1).Value
            firstColumn = firstColumn + 1
        Next j
        wsh.Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
        i = i + groupSize
        dataGroupAddedCount = dataGroupAddedCount + 1
EvaluateNext:
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    'If there was no data, exit
    wsh.Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete
    If dataGroupAddedCount = 0 Then MsgBox "Process completed, NO DATA found.", vbInformation, "Process completed": Exit Sub
    
    'Prompt if want to delete the vertical data
    Dim Ans As String
    Ans = MsgBox("Process completed, " & dataGroupAddedCount & " rows of data were added horizontally." & _
    vbCr & "Do you want to delete the vertical-formated data?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Process completed")
    
    If Ans = vbYes Then wsh.Range("A" & dataGroupAddedCount + 2 & ":A" & lastRow).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so very much!